# RedirectMatch 301 issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have an issue in my RedirectMatch 301 rule.

I want to redirect all urls like theses:

```
http://www.toto.com/lang/fr/tutu/salut-les-gens
http://www.toto.com/lang/fr/tutu/trop-bien
http://www.toto.com/lang/fr/tutu/gg-a-toi
```

to:

```
http://www.toto.com/blog/tutu/salut-les-gens
http://www.toto.com/blog/tutu/trop-bien
http://www.toto.com/blog/tutu/gg-a-toi
```

I have set this rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/lang/fr/tutu/.* /blog/tutu/$1
```

but it's redirections to http://www.toto.com/blog/tutu and not http://www.toto.com/blog/tutu/salut-les-gens

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses to capture content and reuse it in a variable. And you should first try your rules with 302 codes, and not 301. So that if you make any mistake you do not have to close your browser to re-test the new rule (with 301 the browser is not requesting anymore the web server after the first answer).

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/lang/fr/tutu/(.*) /blog/tutu/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, parenthesis was missing it's gerat :).

Comment: @superscral, you should accept this as the answer if it solved your problem.  People will be more likely to help you if you are a 'good citizen' and do what you are supposed to in the system. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)